# For what values of $a, n$ the number $2^a\cdot 3^n+1$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory

Respected All.

Please forgive me as I am unable to understand if it is an off topic. I am stuck in a situation. Change the title if you find inappropriate

What I am willing to know is that if there is any website where I can get complete information on prime numbers. AT present I am engaged on searching primes of the form $2^a3^n+1$ with $a=1,2,3,\cdots$ etc where $n\in \mathbb N$.

Can some one provide me any link/website where if I submit the value of $a, n$ I will get the result immediately if it is prime or not ?

Comment: [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+2^57*3^22%2B1+prime%3F) can work for relatively small values of $a$ and $n$.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose I want to check for $a=2$, $n=1,2,3,\cdots, 100$ how to do that ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierpont_prime

Comment: There is no website with complete information on prime numbers, but seraching specific types of primes will give many results.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So is there any site where if I put a list of values of $n$, we shall get which $2^a3^n+1$ will be prime when $a$ is given?

Comment: Yes, there are tables [here](https://oeis.org/A005109). But of course it would be much better for you, if you write a small program yourself.